# Google Analytics: Filter doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics

I have a property setup that has two main views: sitea.com view and siteb.com view, note that the property default URL is sitea.com.

When I go to the reporting tab for the siteb.com view, and navigate to Acquisition > Social > Landing pages, the shared URL shows both sitea.com results and siteb.com results despite me being in the siteb.com view.

I added a custom filter that filters out sitea.com but when I verified the filter it says that it doesn't have an effect, and when I check the report the site that is excluded still appears in the results.

Picture of results & filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whdgy.jpg

Answer (score 2):

After adding a filter you cant re-verify the same filter (after hitting save). Even setting up the exact same filter in the same view wont let you re-verify the results.

To be able to re-verify your filter you need to delete your filter, and create a new one in the same format and verify prior to saving.

Comment: I verified the filter prior to saving it also and got the same message.  The results of the report don't seem to be filtered either which is what I don't understand. Why would gfcmediagroup.com results appear when there is a filter that specifically excludes that domain?

Comment: The filters wont retroactively adjust your data. If you want to view your historic data with constraints (e.g. excluding gfcmediagroup.com) then you can create a segment. This is also good for testing filters, as you will be able to see the effect that the filter will have on your data.

Comment: I did not realise, apologies - that makes much more sense now. What segment should I create? Ideally, I'd like one that only shows data from the date I created the filter till the present date. Is that possible? I created a segment but it required an end date.